# Post attracting spam?

Tags: support, spam

This post [dpm() does not display any results on screen](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24217/dpm-does-not-display-any-results-on-screen/41270#41270) has been receiving spam suggesstoins for several times today.

I have seen this suggestion (the content slightly differs each time) for the fourth time today (and submission times differ so these are new suggestions):

[image: spam]

The suggestion is done by an anonymous user. Can we block the user (or the thread)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That answer had about [25 spam suggestions rejected recently](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/41270/timeline). The originators of those are already being blocked, automatically:

> If you suggest an edit to a post that has a certain number of edits rejected as spam recently and then that edit is rejected as spam - we deal you a blocking penalty in the spam system.

-- [Tim Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237055).

When rejecting spam edits repeatedly on the same answer gets tedious, a trick may be appropriate: edit the answer to expand it.

> answers longer than a sentence get edits like that auto-rejected by the system, while still banning the associated IPs.

-- [Shog9](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4914920#4914920)

It's not quite clear to me how many characters the answer needs to have in order for this to kick in: Shog9 said it's [400 some places, 200 others](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=4914932#4914932). Anyway, it's worth trying (by someone familiar with the subject): add another paragraph to the post, 1-2 sentences should be enough.

Comment: Thanks, I will remember that for the future. :)